# pyth error [rtf to xml/html]

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, rtf

I am trying to convert RTF to XML/xhtml using python 3.6.1.

Python Code: https://github.com/brendonh/pyth/blob/master/examples/reading/rtf15.py

```
import sys
import os.path

from pyth.plugins.rtf15.reader import Rtf15Reader
from pyth.plugins.xhtml.writer import XHTMLWriter

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
else:
    filename = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../../tests/rtfs/sample.rtf'))  

doc = Rtf15Reader.read(open(filename, "rb"))
print(XHTMLWriter.write(doc, pretty=True).read())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xx\file1.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pyth.plugins.rtf15.reader import Rtf15Reader
  File "C:\Python 3.6.1\lib\site-packages\pyth\plugins\rtf15\reader.py", line 594
    match = re.match(ur'HYPERLINK "(.*)"', destination)
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

May I know how to solve the syntax issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the link:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyth/0.6.0

The `pyth` package is just used for Python 2.x, not worked for Python 3.x version.

PS：
At you sample code, the

```
print XHTMLWriter.write(doc, pretty=True).read()
```

is the Python 2.x version, not Python 3.x version. Please check.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error when running the code with () for python3. Is there an alternative to convert rtf file to other file types?

Answer (score 0):

`pyth` package is now available for python3 as well. Install `pyth3` package:

```
py -3 -m pip install pyth3
```